# Post to website through email

Tags: php, email

I'm currently working on a PHP application. In order for me to post data to the website, I create a simple form, nothing trivial. However, I would like to incorporate a functionality of posting data in the form of email. So I have a webserver, I have an email set up, and what I would like to do is to send a message to that email, then the sent data is stored. I'm trying to find resources how to do this one and to no avail. Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: from what you have, you might not be able to do it.
you need to write your own email server, or buy some service, software that read through your email. then setup your email format to let program read it and execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mailgun has an inbound email API, which will post incoming email messages to your application.  See http://www.mailgun.com/inbound-routing.  Sendgrid also offers a similar service: https://sendgrid.com/blog/sendgrids-parse-api-parsing-incoming-email-is-now-faster-and-easier/

Comment: I didn't know that its going to be that complicated through code. I guess its worth trying to use a 3rd party API to save time.

Answer (score 2):

It's called email piping, and its a bit hands on so far as configuring it with your email server. If you're comfortable, here's a decent quick rundown: http://www.phpshare.org/articles/Piping-Incoming-Mail-with-PHP

I believe the above is what you're looking for, however an alternative would be having a specific subject / attachment name, and having a cron job periodically check your email account looking for that specific string. ( Option A is a much better / easier fit, but thought it was worth mentioning).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the keyword "email piping", I did a research and it looks like my host supports forwarders, all I need to do now is to set it up, and parse the code in PHP.

Comment: No problem. Most support / helpdesk systems use that very trick. If you're using cPanel, you're golden as it is super simple to setup. One very important detail -- MAKE ABSOLUTELY SURE YOU SANITIZE THE INBOUND DATA. This might mean matching for a special/secret hash, holding updates for manual approval, prepared statements, only accepting inbound connections via email ssl, or any and all other precautions you can think of. Opening access like that while incredibly cool/neat/fun/amazing, can destroy your site and databases in many terrifying ways (even if it was yourself, on accident).